# Зачем нужен флаг в данном методе?

Tags: javascript

Для чего нужен флаг в данном коде? Ведь и так понятно, что при вызове метода destroy, прослушиватель удалиться... или же флаг действует, как переключатель для единовременного использования? Можете простым языком это пояснить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> при вызове метода destroy, прослушиватель удалиться

И как Вы потом об этом узнаете?

---

Напишите

```
counter = "Analytics destroyed";
```

вместо

```
isDestroyed = true;
```

и

```
getClick() {
  return counter;
}
```

Обойдетесь без флага.

Comment: А когда вообще флаги нужны? Или можно просто return их подвинуть?

Comment: @Dresosr На демонстрации. Я не понял, что Вы спрашиваете. Когда нужно выразить состояние `да/нет`.

Comment: я имею можно ли флаги заменить return-ом?

Comment: @Dresosr "флаги заменить return-ом" - Это бессмысленная фраза. Нет, нельзя.

Comment: просто вот в этой статья флаг в некотором случае заменяется ретурном http://code.mu/ru/javascript/book/prime/functions/flags/

Comment: @Dresosr Ну и что?